# Ways to get rid of "conditional expression is constant" warning when checking bool template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

This code template produces the "conditional expression is constant" warning when compiled with /W4 (MSVC 2013):

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool condition>
struct Conditional
{
    static void f()
    {
        if (condition)
            std::cout << "true";
        else
            std::cout << "false";
    }
};

void main()
{
    Conditional<false>::f();
}
```

Now, assume `Conditional` is actually a useful class with lots of methods and lots of code around the condition. I want to get rid of the warning with as little code modification as possible.

The only one trick I know is tag dispatching. It's acceptable, but a bit clumsy since I need to declare 2 additional methods and extract the condition code there. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Tag dispatch sounds like overkill.  Did you mean template specialization?

Comment: The way I solve this in Java is that I have a globally visible static `get` function which accepts anything as a parameter and returns it unchanged.  So, the code would look like this: `if( get( condition ) ) ...` Since the compiler does not know how the function works, it does not consider the condition as constant anymore.  Can't you do anything similar in C++?

Comment: @DrewDormann: I meant tag dispatching; specialization indeed looks well-suited for this case.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I can, but it's really ugly!

Comment: I would be tempted to bet that it must be the least ugly of the alternatives. And you can wrap it in a macro which expands to the parameter itself (no function call) when compiling for release.

Answer (score 4):

You may use specialization:

```
template <bool condition>
struct Conditional
{
    static void f();
};

template <>
void Conditional<true>::f() { std::cout << "true"; }

template <>
void Conditional<false>::f() { std::cout << "false"; }
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/EklgEx)

Comment: Probably a silly question, but I can still do that if the `bool` is not the only template parameter, right? That will be partial specialization? And it will still work fine if `f()` is a non-static virtual method?

Comment: Actually you can only define the method inline with its specialization if the specialization is an *explicit speclialization*. Otherwise (if it is partial) you have to define the specialization of the class first and then change the method.

Comment: ^ because there are no partial specializations of functions

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 and onward, `if constexpr` solves this problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool condition>
struct Conditional
{
    static void f()
    {
        if constexpr (condition) // No warning because the branch is calculated 
                                 // at compile time and not present at runtime.
            std::cout << "true";
        else
            std::cout << "false";
    }
};

void main()
{
    Conditional<false>::f();
}
```